# Drill Down,DetailView and Interface Builder Problems

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to build a drill-down IPad app.
I started with the SplitViewController. I created two more 
more TableViewControllers. I successfully added the two 
TableViewControllers and can get drill down navigation.

The problem is that when I am at the bottom of the drill down, 
I need to get a reference to the DetailViewController. Try as I might, 
I am unable to get interface builder to link the DetailView to the 
IBOutlet in my bottom most controller.

I am currently using XCode 3.2. No upgrade option yet. How do I get the 
reference to my DetailViewController into my bottom level TableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not reference a distant parent view controller after drilling down to a detail view controller.

- If you need information from the parent, just pass it down the chain as properties.
- If you need to pass information up, do it via delegate protocols.
- If you need some kind of global variable, use the application delegate.